# Backbone Marionette Disable and Enable events using Wreqr

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone Marionette and exploiting it's Event Aggregator. I'm kinda stuck in this scenario wherein I can't trigger the previously offed event (using `.off()`).

Consider the code sample below:

```
vent.on('generateStat');
vent.off('generateStat');
vent.on('generateStat'); // Non trigger-able anymore
```

How can I do this? On second thought, what's a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you try to re-explain what you mean?